# Wrapping text in C# dialog box

Tags: c#, user-interface, word-wrap

I've got a dialog box that pops up with a dynamic list of numbers, and I'd like to get the box to wrap the text because at the moment it displayed up to screen width and then cuts the rest off.

I know I can use `\n` to declare a new line, but the list is dynamic - it could be one item, it could be 20.

Is there any way to tell the dialog box to wrap text?

**Edit:** clarification + example code

I'm not using `MessageBox.Show()` - our code uses its own defined message box class, but the guts of it calls `System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(parent)`. Maybe this isn't as well-behaved (i.e., doesn't wrap) as `MessageBox.Show()`?

Comment: Can you add some sample code that shows this? It sounds like you're using `MessageBox.Show()` but that should automatically wrap text nicely, even if there aren't any separators in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own simple form and add a label. Do the wrapping there... You cannot do that much things with Dialog boxes.
In this way you have much more flexibility to show your information to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what will have to be done. I know dialog boxes are simple, but I think they really should have a simple word wrap!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`? It has a property `WordWrap` that you can set to true

Comment: it's not a text box for inputting text, it's a dialog box for displaying text

Answer (score 0):

No other way for a standart MessageBox. Only creating your own form.

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically format the text by restricting each line to a specific number of words then inserting a `\n` or `Envoronment.NewLine`

Comment: This would work but it feels a little hacky. I'd rather not hard-code a set number of words, as the text may change in the future (adding actual language sentences as well, which may cause the 'X words per line' rule to misbehave)

Comment: I would create your own form then, with a scrollable text box if you really need to have specific things on each line without changing any formatting.